# Excelfile to DataGridview with ClosedXML

Tags: c#, datagridview, closedxml

In my project I have to import an Excelfile. The type is .xlsx. The file has a table in it with 4 columns. I have to add extra columns to this excel file. My problem is that with my solution the DataGridview has the headertext twice. And every time I read the file again I get a new row with the headertext. I think the problem is in the foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells()) but I do not find out there the bug is.

```
try
{

    OpenFileDialog OpenDataList = new OpenFileDialog();// Erzeugen einen OpenFileDialog-Objektes
    OpenDataList.Title = "Datenpunktliste öffnen"; // Initialisiert den Namen des Fensters
    OpenDataList.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\AdministratorOSMO\Desktop\Testordner"; // Legt den Default Dateipfad fest
    OpenDataList.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx"; // Filter für die zur Auswahl stehenden Dateitypen
    OpenDataList.FilterIndex = 2;// Legt den Standardfilter beim Öffnen fest

    if (OpenDataList.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)//Abfrage ob der ShowDialog mit OK bestätigt wurde
    {
        string PathName = OpenDataList.FileName;// die Variable pathName wird mit dem Inhalt von Filename initialisiert
        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(PathName))//Arbeitmappe wird erstellt
        {

            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);//Tabelle 1 der Excel-Datei wird in workSheet geschrieben
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();// neuer DataTable dt wird erzeugt
            bool firstRow = true;// Boolsche Variable für Erste Reihe ?
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                while (firstRow)

                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }

                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OK", typeof(bool)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Datum", typeof(string)));
                    firstRow = false;
                }

                dt.Rows.Add();

                int i = 0;
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                    i++;
                }

                Dgv_Data_List.DataSource = dt;
                Dgv_Data_List.ReadOnly = true;

            }

        }                                       
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you set your column headers from the first row you also handle the same row as a normal data row. You can stop that by using `continue` to go to the next row. (Also the last two lines below can go outside the foreach loop.)

```
foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
{
    if (firstRow)       
    {
        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
        }

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OK", typeof(bool)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Datum", typeof(string)));
        firstRow = false;
        continue;  // go to next row
    }

    dt.Rows.Add();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
    {
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
        i++;
    }
}

Dgv_Data_List.DataSource = dt;
Dgv_Data_List.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Change the `while` to `if`, you don't need the `while` loop (the `continue` went to the `while` loop instead of the `foreach` loop, that was the problem with my first version.) BTW: You should'nt post a reply to my answer as a seperate answer to the question.